# Minimize $ {x}^{T} Q y $ subject to $ \left\| x \right\|^{2} + \left\| y \right\|^{2} = 1 $

Tags: matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

Let $ Q $ be an $ n \times n $ diagonal matrix with *positive* diagonal entries $\lambda_{1}<\cdots<\lambda_{n}$.

Find local minimizer(s) for the function $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and show which 1st and 2nd order conditions satisfy:

I want to minimize: $ f(x, y)= {x}^{T} Q y $ subject to $ \left\| x \right\|^{2} + \left\| y \right\|^{2} = 1 $ for $ x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n $.

Here's what I have tried: I see that all feasible points are regular points, so I can find all minimizer candidates using Lagrange multipliers.

Letting $g(x,y) = |x|^2+|y|^2-1$, I set
$$\nabla f + \lambda \nabla g = \left(\begin{array}{cc}Qy+\lambda 2x\\Qx+\lambda2y\end{array}\right):= {\bf 0}.$$

I'm not quite sure how to proceed here. Am I missing something in how to tackle this kind of problem?

Comment: It may be helpful to note that your equation can be written as
$$
x = -\frac{1}{2\lambda}Qy, \qquad 
y = -\frac{1}{2\lambda}Qx
$$
Which yields
$$
x = \frac{1}{4 \lambda^2}Q^2x
$$
via substitution.  In particular, we're looking for eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $Q^2$

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I got it from there, thanks!

Comment: @Royi in the original, $\cdot$ denotes the dot product.  You should either write $x \cdot Qy$ or something like $x^TQy$; $xQy$ has no traditional interpretation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, So trivial I missed it :-). Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full answer, per the suggestion in the comments:

Your equation for the candidate minimizers (via Lagrange's method) can be written as
$$
x = - \frac{1}{2 \lambda}Qy, \quad y = -\frac{1}{2\lambda} Qx
$$
If we use the second equation to substitute into the first, we obtain 
$$
x = \frac{1}{4\lambda^2}Q^2x
$$
So, $\lambda$ will correspond to a candidate minimizer if and only if $\frac{1}{4\lambda^2}$ is an eigenvalue of $Q$, and $x$ must be an associated eigenvector.

From there, we must scale $x$ appropriately so that it fits the constraint $|x|^2 + |y|^2 = 1$.  In particular, $x$ must satisfy the condition
$$
|x|^2 + \frac{1}{2|\lambda|}|Qx|^2 = 1 \implies\\
|x|^2 + \frac 1{2 |\lambda|}x^TQ^TQx = 1
$$
This simplifies significantly in the case that $Q$ is symmetric (which is true in this case since $Q$ is diagonal).  In particular, since $Q = Q^T$, the equation above becomes
$$
|x|^2 + \frac 1{2 |\lambda|}x^TQ^2x = 1 \implies\\
|x|^2 + \frac 1{2 |\lambda|}x^T(4 \lambda^2 x) = 1 \implies\\
(1 + 2 |\lambda|)|x|^2 = 1 \implies\\
|x|^2 = \frac{1}{1 + 2 |\lambda|}
$$